# JVM crashes frequently

Tags: jboss, elasticsearch, lucene, jvm, jvm-hotspot

JVM crashes surprizingly and frequently on our prod environment and results in Jboss (EAP6.3) going down. We have java7 U72 installed

Crash logs has same output where current thread is:

> Current thread (0x00000000d1d99000):  JavaThread "Lucene Merge Thread #0" daemon [_thread_in_Java, id=1144, stack(0x00000000f6a00000,0x00000000f6b00000)]

and all the log is full of :

> JavaThread "elasticsearch[Node BD852E44][search][T#68]" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14396, stack(0x00000000f7b30000,0x00000000f7c30000)]

elasticsearch is some were related to indexing and it uses Lucene in hood as far as I understand but we have number or application deployed how to check on this can someone please help. complete crash logs are at : http://pastebin.com/845LU9iK

Comment: Could you paste the complete crashlog? Crashes already are hard to diagnose, if you strip out context it only gets more difficult

Comment: It wont let me past full l ogs here ..can you suggest how to do it ?

Comment: pastebin or gist.github

Comment: http://pastebin.com/845LU9iK ...here are full logs

Comment: Make sure you are not running G1 garbage collector. See https://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/JavaBugs for more details.

Comment: thanks @mindas - I am an Admin not sure how to check if GC1 is running ot not can you please let me know how to check that ?...I am not sure if you heared about Appian BPM software which  is hosted by Jboss application server when we contacted Appian Support the also mentioned something related GC so this is something I am intrested checking for...

Comment: @mindas According to the crash dump, CMS GC is used, not G1.

Comment: So the situation with collector is fine or there something I have to check for CMS GC as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it didn't manage to record stack traces for the affected thread.
If that's the same for all crashes then it doesn't seem to match known lucene or jboss bugs.

```
#  guarantee(result == EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION) failed: Unexpected result from topLevelExceptionFilter
```

AIUI this indicates an error in native exception handling, so it's one error masking another, probably making this crash log fairly useless.

So I can only provide really generic advice:

- you're using an older JVM version, update to the latest java 7, java 8 or possibly even a java 9 dev build and see if it goes away.
   Even if they still crash they might provide different/more useful error reports
- to diagnose potential compiler bugs you can try running with the following flags

  - `-XX:-TieredCompilation` <sup>1</sup>  should disable the C1 compiler
  - `-XX:+TieredCompilation -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1` should disable the C2 compiler
  - `-Xint` disables all JIT, very slow
- ask on the [hotspot-dev](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/mailman/listinfo/hotspot-dev) mailing list for further guidance

<sup>1</sup>: [Tiered compilation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/performance-enhancements-7.html#tieredcompilation) is a new java 7 feature, it basically combines the interpreter, C1 and C2 JIT compilers (which formerly were used separately in the client and server VMs) into different optimizing stages.

Each of them can have optimization bugs. Turning off individual stages helps isolating them as potential cause.

---

Edit: The new crash report is more useful since it at least has java frames, the interesting part is the following:

```
J 1559  sun.misc.Unsafe.getByte(J)B (0 bytes) @ 0x000000000178e99b [0x000000000178e960+0x3b]
j  java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.get()B+11
j  org.apache.lucene.store.ByteBufferIndexInput.readByte()B+4
J 9447 C2 org.apache.lucene.store.DataInput.readVInt()I (114 bytes) @ 0x000000000348cc00 [0x000000000348cbc0+0x40]
```

`DataInput.readVInt` seems to be an ongoing source of grief, see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8232459/1362755) for possible solutions

Comment: We have recently promoted java to  jdk1.7.0_72 from jdk1.6.0_26...the issue still persist not sure is promoting java to next level would be helpful ...Is there a way to find out native code of which applicatino is triggering Lucene ...? Also I am not sure how and what will happen is I ran disable compiler flag ...so running blind on Prod environment is something which can severly degrade the situation ...is there link I can refer to get more details on the flags you supplied ?

Comment: If you don't want to do this on production I recommend setting up an environment that replicates production and reproduce the issue there. That or live with performance degradation while testing, i'm assume that crashing JVMs are not any better than slow JVMs. I'll add some details regarding the parameters.

Comment: "Is there a way to find out native code of which applicatino is triggering Lucene". Not sure what you're asking.

Comment: For these point we are not sure what is the trigger to hit the issue scenario to happen or how to induce the problem...so thought lot but reached no were. We have multiple application deployed on Prod and not sure which application is using Lucene ...so I asked que...'is there a way to find out native code of which applicatino is triggering Lucene'...if we can find that we will disable or remove the functionality until this is fixed...

Comment: The request was not approved to try disabling compiler and troubleshoot. Instead we did a JVM split and we added a one more JBoss instance to take care of search server which uses elasticsearch(Lucene).Now we have two jvm instances running one for main ear directory and one for search server. and crash happened again (surprizingly main ear jvm crashed and search server was up and running)this monday can crash logs are at : http://pastebin.com/wWWG9edh can someone review

Comment: I am not sure weather it was a bug or there us something else ...we kept moving from newer and to newer version and finally Java version 7 update 78, we are not facing JVM crash issue any more thanks all for your help for now the issue resolved